# How to change AC(auto-completion) colors of dabbrev

Tags: emacs, attributes, face

How to change AC(auto-completion) colors of dabbrev
   I've tried to change these colors on my init.el

```
(set-face-attribute 'ac-dabbrev-menu-face nil :inherit ac-candidate-face :foreground nil)
(set-face-attribute 'ac-dabbrev-selection-face nil :inherit ac-selection-face :background nil)
(set-face-attribute 'ac-etags-candidate-face nil :foreground nil)
(set-face-attribute 'ac-etags-selection-face nil :background nil)
```

But it didn't work and gave me an error like this.
Please let me know if there's a way to do this.

PS : I'm using "monokai-theme" which provides the faces of ac-candidate/selection-face

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the new theme API (likely), use `custom-theme-set-faces`.  I'm just pasting my settings in, because I'm too lazy to test with yours.  I'm not entirely sure what setting an attribute to `nil` does.

```
  (load-theme 'calmer-forest 'noconfirm)
  (custom-theme-set-faces
   'calmer-forest

   '(ac-completion-face ((t (:foreground "green3"))))
   '(ac-selection-face ((t (:background "gray9" :foreground "magenta"))))
   '(ac-candidate-face ((t (:background "gray16" :foreground "lavender"))))
   '(ac-gtags-selection-face ((t (:inherit ac-selection-face))))
   '(ac-gtags-candidate-face ((t (:inherit ac-candidate-face))))
   '(ac-yasnippet-selection-face ((t (:inherit ac-selection-face))))
   '(ac-yasnippet-candidate-face ((t (:inherit ac-candidate-face))))
  ))
```